# Is it possible to pipe head output to sed?

Tags: bash, sed

Input file

```
hello how are u
some what doing fine
so 
thats all
huh
thats great
cool
gotcha im fine
```

I wanted to remove last 4 lines without re directing to another file or say in place edit.

I used `head -n -3 input.txt` but its removing only the last 2 lines.

Also wanted to understand is it possible to pipe head's output to sed

like `head -n -3 input.txt | sed ...`

Yes, I went thru sed's option to remove last n lines like below but couldn't understand the nuances of the command so went ahead with the alternative of head command

```
sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,5ba' -e 'P;D' file
```

Comment: `head -n -3 input.txt but its removing only the last 2 lines` that doesn't seem right.. what's the output you get for `seq 10 | head -n -3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Without creating a temp file solution:

```
awk -i inplace -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) 'FNR<=(lines-4)' Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
tac Input_file | tail -n +5 | tac  > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `awk`.

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) 'FNR<=(lines-4)' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as expected, but say If I have to delete the last 5 lines, in that scenario ??

Comment: Yes that's one way of doing but I'm exploring the possibilities of editing in place instead of creating a temp file.. Many thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: @dev, please check my solution 2nd now?

Comment: @dev most tools that "do" in-place editing, create a temp file as well, you just don't see it. So what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: @dev, if your `awk` supports inplace option please check my EDIT option then and let me know?

Comment: @dev, also try to search forum too for questions and you could get the answers exact or near by to your question too, cheers and happy learning.